# For Comprehension Type Checking

Tags: scala

Can anyone tell me if something in the line with the following syntax is possible in Scala?

```
  @annotation.tailrec
  def traverse[E,A,B](es: List[A])(f: A => Either[E, B]): Either[E, List[B]] = {
    def go(es: List[A], rs: Either[E, List[B]]): Either[E, List[B]] = {
      es match {
        case Nil => rs
        case x::xs => for {
          Right(b) <- f(x);
          Right(ls) <- rs
        } yield go(xs, Right(b::ls))
      }
    }

    go(es, Right(List()))
  }
```

I keep getting the following syntax exception

```
Error:(47, 12) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : A$A400.this.Right[A]
 required: List[?B3] where type ?B3 <: B (this is a GADT skolem)
          Right(ls) <- rs
          ^
```

Comment: Try matching on rs being either Left or Right?

Comment: thats what I'm trying to achieve but  I get that exception

Comment: I think it unlikely the compiler will work out your function is tailrecursive. The for will desugar into flatmap/Map and be passed the yield as a function. It's asking a bit much of the compiler to work out that that is a tail call.

Comment: What should happen when rs, does not match `Right(ls)`, or the first element of `es` does not match `Right(b)`?

Comment: Good Point @TheArchetypalPaul, didnt think it quite through it seems

Comment: making it tail recursive is also making it a little ugly it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what the aim of the function is, but, guessing at what `f` is, here's something that may do what you want?

```
@annotation.tailrec
  def f[A, B, E](e: A): Either[E, B] = ???

  def go[A, B, E](es: List[A], rs: Either[E, List[B]]): Either[E, List[B]] = {
    es match {
      case Nil => rs
      case x :: xs => (f(x), rs) match {
        case (Right(b), Right(ls)) => go(xs, Right(b :: ls))
      }
    }

    go(es, Right(List()))
  }
```